# how to extract value from splunk and generate line graph

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My log messages

```
.o.s.c.PaymentMethodInstrumentController : Exiting ServiceController.getMyServiceDetails() : elapsedTime(ms):34, xrfRequestId:c3b5878d-8795-49cb-b6a7-51ab02789f46, xCorrelationId:786d68ea-ze46-42b9-966f-124f2eb444f6, xForwardedFor:10.242.79.96

.o.s.c.PaymentMethodInstrumentController : Exiting ServiceController.getMyServiceDetails() : elapsedTime(ms):39, xrfRequestId:c3b2c08d-6c6d-49cb-b6a7-51a89897446, xCorrelationId:78676yt64-ze46-42b9-966f-124f2eb444f6, xForwardedFor:10.242.79.96
```

I am looking to extract elapsedTime(ms):34 and generate the line graph of these values.

Comment: What do you mean by `line graph`? Is it `timechart`?

Comment: yes as Line Chart under 'Visualization' section.

Comment: So you already have `_time`, right?

Comment: Yes. I want to extract 'elapsedTime(ms):34' from the log statement and show in line chart to see what the elapsed time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have `_time`, something like that:

```
<your search>
| rex "elapsedTime(ms):(?<elapsedTime>\d+),"
| table _time elapsedTime
```

Comment: It is showing the _time table value but elapsedTime column is empty.

Comment: It worked after adding \ before ( 

| rex "elapsedTime\(ms\):(?<elapsedTime>\d+),"|table _time elapsedTime